# I don't know opencv Error about code checking footsize

Tags: opencv

I want to make program checking my foot-size

I don't know this error about opencv

url: http://cocoding94.blogspot.com/2017/05/blog-post_7.html .

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2

img = cv2.imread("foot.jpeg")

blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,10))

rows,cols,ch = img.shape

pts1 = np.float32([170,270],[480,220],[240, 710],[540,650])
pts2 = np.float32([0,0],[210,0],[0,297],[210,297])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(210,297))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')

plt.plot(*zip(*point), marker='.', color='r', ls='')

plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')

plt.show()
```

---

In raspberry pi error printing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "foot.py",line 7,in  
>   blur = cv2. blur (img,(5,10)) cv2.error:OpenCV(3.4.3)
>   /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.4.3/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:756: error:
>   (-215:Assertion failed) dims <=2 && step[0] > 0 in function
>   'locateROI'

Comment: There is a high chance that your image was not loaded successfully. Are you sure "foot.jpeg" exists in the current working directory? maybe try using the full path. You can use print (img.shape) after loading the image to make sure it was loaded successfully

Answer (score 0):

but please next time add more information to make this community greater than another, I fixed some errors in your code, i don´t your original image, but the code now works well, try to change your point to get a good perspective:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("machupichu.jpg")
#blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
#rows,cols,ch = img.shape

point=[[170,270],[480,220],[240, 710],[540,650]]

pts1 = np.float32([[170,270],[480,220],[240, 710],[540,650]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[210,0],[0,297],[210,297]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(210,297))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Input')

plt.plot(*zip(*point), marker='.', color='r', ls='')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

Here is the image which I used:
[Machu Pichu](http://www.dream-wallpaper.com/free-wallpaper/travel-wallpaper/machu-picchu-wallpaper/1920x1200/free-wallpaper-14.jpg)
This is the result:
[image: result]

Best Regards.

Comment: we have another error.  : Traceback (most recent call last): File "foot.py",line 17,in <modules> dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(210,297))         cv2.error:OpenCV(3.4.3) /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.4.3/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:756: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <=2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'

Comment: Please check well that you have installed opencv well or try uninstalling and reinstall it

Comment: May i ask another problem? please let me know your e-mail. thank you very much.

Comment: No problem , it is creatorpart@gmail.com

Comment: please check your e-mail:)